# remove files in shell and not the directory of the same name

Tags: shell

I need to remove files with name `file1` in a folder `folder1`

`folder1` has `file1`[unix exec file] and `file1`[a folder].

If I use

`find /pathto_folder -iname "file1" -delete`

It deletes both, the file and the folder, How to make the script del only file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
find /pathto_folder -type f -iname "file1" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find /path/to/folder -name 'file1' -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be case-sensitive problem.

on linux/unix box, under same parent, you cannot create a directory and file  with exactly same name. 
in your case, it could be

```
"file1" ->the file 
"File1" -> the dir
```

so just change the `-iname` to `-name` and give the right filename (e.g. file1) then try again.

Comment: yes, well it was in the child folder, i realised after your comment. But the find function deletes everything, the file and the folder.